# Postgresql. select SUM value from arrays

Tags: postgresql

**Condition**:

There are two tables with arrays.

Note **food.integer and price.food_id specified array**.

```
CREATE TABLE food (
    id integer[] NOT NULL,
    name character varying(255),
);
INSERT INTO food VALUES ('{1}', 'Apple');
INSERT INTO food VALUES ('{1,1}', 'Orange');
INSERT INTO food VALUES ('{1,2}', 'banana');
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE  price (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    food_id integer[],
    value double precision DEFAULT 0
);
INSERT INTO price VALUES (44, '{1}', 500);
INSERT INTO price VALUES (55, '{1,1}', 100);
INSERT INTO price VALUES (66, '{1,2}', 200);
```

Need to get the sum value of all the products from table food. 
Please help make a sql query.

ANSWER:
 {1} - Apple - 800 (500+100+200)

Comment: If you normalize your data model this becomes a *very* easy query. Storing foreign key references in an array is not a good idea. You should really consider fixing your data model

Comment: Yes, but I do not this base designed.
If you know a query to this database, write or tell me where to look.

Comment: Why did I know you were going to tell us you didn't do it? The people creating wrong data models apparently never have to use them. I don't understand the array of ids in the `food` table. Does this mean "banana" has two different ids? And why does Orange have the same IDs as Apple? And what does it mean that "Orange" and "Banana" have *two* ids. What is the primary key of the `food` table? The model and the data do not make any sense to me.

Comment: You're right. This very bad model batabase.
But I do not this base designed

Comment: Can you please answer my questions regarding your example data. I just don't understand how the two tables are related and what it means that a single food can have multiple "ID"s and what if means if they are the same and what it means if they are different

Comment: ID in table food (food.id) not as a unique identifier field, but for grouping (a common feature) fields.

price.food_id - price for this group id (a common feature fields).

Here the question is how to find fields with overlapping values ​​arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
select 
  name,
  sum(value)
from
  (select unnest(id) as food_id, name from food) food_cte
  join (select distinct id, unnest(food_id) as food_id, value from price) price_cte using (food_id)
group by
  name
```

It is difficult to understand your question, but this query at least returns 800 for Apple.

Comment: Yes this is it!

I need only grouping by food.ID, not food.name :(

Answer (score 0):

try the following command,

```
SELECT F.ID,F.NAME,SUM(P.VALUE) FROM FOOD F,PRICE P WHERE F.ID=P.FOOT_ID;
```

Comment: Need for separateness for product:
Apple - 800 (500+100+200);
Orange - ...;
Banana - ...;

Comment: there are no multiple prices for apple in your price table.

Comment: What sum price.value for apples?
800 (500+100+200) or other?

Comment: food.id=price.food_id is satisfied and your price table contains two or more records for a single id all the price values for an id will be  added to sum().

Comment: But food.integer and price.food_id specified array.
Сan make better use of design: unnest(F.ID) = any(P.FOOT_ID) ?